# Firefox is running out of disk space. Website contents may not display properly

Tags: dual-boot, firefox, live-usb, persistence

I'm getting this error in Firefox on a Yumi multiboot Ubuntu 20.04 Live USB with Persistence.  It also says "Visit "Learn More" to optimize your disk usage for better browsing experience." and I have done all that is suggested, I've even reset Firefox but the error continues

Comment: Could you [edit] you question to include the following details? ⇢ Does Firefox know to use your president storage for its cache files? How much storage is available? What sort of sites are you viewing in Firefox? (Streaming sites will use GB with no hesitation)

Comment: I do not know how to get the answers to those questions, this is my first time running a live usb with persistence, but I'll start looking that information and edit my question.  I know maybe 10 commands, everything else I have to look up.

Comment: What tool was used to make your Persistent USB? Some tools like UNetbootin are limited to a 4GB persistence file which is not very much. Others like Rufus and mkusb use persistent partitions which can almost be as big as the USB. Of course the total disk space also depends on the size of the USB. Trying to update the USB can also use up space very quickly.

Comment: YUMI BIOS version has unlimited* persistence, YUMI UEFI version is limited to 4GB persistence. *Only limited by size of drive.